# How to pass object to other component, on route change data is getting cleared

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to pass an object to another component. Below is my approach. But data is getting cleared on route changed. Is there any fix for this or is there any other solution.

**In Component 1:**

```
this.myService.setData(this.myData);
this.router.navigateByUrl('component2');
```

**In-Service:**

```
private myDataSubj = new Subject<MyData>();
setData(myData) {
    this.myDataSubj.next(myData);
}
getData(): Observable<MyData> {
    return this.myDataSubj.asObservable();
}
```

**In Component 2:**
*in ngOninit*

```
this.myService.getData().subscribe(data => {
     this.myData = data;
     console.log(this.myData); // Returning Undefined. 
  })
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: How yo declare `In-Service` class (is `@Injectable` used?)? Did you add `In-Service` to `providers` of `NgModule`? What is sequence of launching your two component? From code you provided it's unclear...

Comment: There is no problem in what you are asking.. What I want is I want to parse data to other component, data should be there even if you changed the route, If you know better approach please suggest.

Comment: Is the service a singleton? Do you have `providedIn: 'root'` in the service?

Comment: you can simply keep a global variable in your service and that variable in the component

Comment: @SheenaSingla Can you please write a code for that?

Comment: In service - mydata: Data; // Data is the datatype, you can create the interface for that. In Component - constructor(private admin:AdminService){} getData(){const d = this.admin.myData};

Comment: Is your component2 initialized before component 1 sends data? Because if not, then I think component2 may miss the data sent by subject. You can look at BehaviourSubject or ReplaySubjects also

Comment: Do you have any reason to use rxjs's `Subject`? If no, you can simply use Angular's [Route Parameters](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Please read the angular documentation or do some research before asking.
Please read about [Angular component interaction using service](https://v5.angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)

On a high level what you want is... [see below]

#### Update

To support in Angular 5

#### Module

```
providers: [SharedService]
exports: [SharedService]
```

#### Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs';
import { SharedService } from '........<module path>...';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

  // Observable string sources
  private myDataSubj = new Subject<MyData>();

  // Observable string streams
  public myDataSubj$ = this.myDataSubj.asObservable();

  // Service method
  sharedData(myData: MyData) {
    this.myDataSubj.next(myData);
    this.myDataSubj.complete();
  }

}
```

#### Component-1

```
this.sharedService.sharedData(data);
```

#### Component-2

```
this.sharedService.myDataSubj$.subscribe(data => {
    this.myData= data;
    console.log(this.myData);
});
```

Comment: My angular version is 5, provided in root won't work.

Comment: That's not valid excuse @SwamyReddy. As an engineer, you have to know how to deal with multiple versions. Just remove `providedIn` property and inject it in providers in the module and export it from there and import in your component.

Comment: @SwamyReddy, I have updated the answer. Please see. and link points to the angular 5 version.

Comment: even though, in component 2 subscribe is not getting inside.